# How can I view all the JIRA tickets I'm watching?

Tags: jira, jql

I clicked watcher for many JIRA tickets, but I can't find a filter that shows me all the tickets I am watching. Can someone direct me to the right link or filter to look.

Comment: JIRA is such a dumpster fire.

Answer (score 35):

Type in the Jira issues search (Issues > Search for issues): `key in watchedIssues()`

or go directly to the URL, like to your JIRA domain `http://<your-jira-domain>/jira/issues/?jql=key%20in%20watchedIssues()`

There is also a gadget you can add to your JIRA homepage (dashboard): [Watched Issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-watched-issues-gadget-720417021.html)

From the top right button "add gadget", then on the pop-pup search for "watched" and you will get it.

Comment: Adding the watch gadget was a simple & easy solution.  Although, I had to make a separate dashboard to add it.

Answer (score 12):

If you open up a "New search". Then the filter below will show you, your watched tasks:

```
watcher = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC
```

Hope it suits you :-)

Comment: The URL link would like this, https://jira.com/issues/?jql=watcher%20%3D%20currentUser()%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I'd discovered this Jira trick months ago!